# Publish .NetCore app with profile

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

I have a simple solution and in it a folder and a csproj with a Hello World `.NET Core 2.0` console application.

I created a publish profile for a self-contained win-x64 release.

When I publish this in VS 2017 everything's peachy.

The publish profile is relative to the csproj in `Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml`

But I just can't get it to publish on the command line, neither with `msbuild.exe` nor with `dotnet.exe`.

The publish command executes and actually creates a publish folder. It's just not in the place configured in the profile nor does it contain an actual `exe` (just the same built dlls as in the `bin` folder).

Standard internet search tells me to do it this way:

```
dotnet publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile ConsoleApp3.csproj
```

Sometimes people specify the `.pubxml` extension. Tried that.

I also tried the `msbuild.exe` variation:

```
msbuild.exe /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile ConsoleApp3.csproj
```

The result was the same.

Comment: Do u found solution? Has the same problem.

Comment: I never found a way to use a publishing profile. However, I managed to publish by command-line only. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never actually found a way to publish with a profile. However, I managed to create a command line that resulted in what I wanted:

```
dotnet.exe publish -c Release -r win-x64 -o publish --self-contained true MyProject.csproj
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to publish to a specific folder, this definitely works:

```
dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp2.1 --output "c:\PUBLISHED\ProofOfConcept" --configuration Debug
```

Personally I prefer to create a batch file (.bat) that contains the code below, then I just double click it:

```
TaskKill /F /IM dotnet.exe
iisreset /stop
cd C:\MyProjects\ProofOfConcept\ProofOfConcept
dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp2.1 --output "c:\PUBLISHED\ProofOfConcept" --configuration Debug
iisreset /start
pause
```